# Oauth2 access token expiration based on user account

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid

We have our own openid and Oauth2 based authorization server. We have a use case where we want to control the access token issued to expire after one use. This use case is specific to user account. For example user1@client1 should get an access token which should expire after single use whereas user2@client1 should use the default expiration where the token will expire after x seconds but can be used multiple times.

Thanks
Ranjith

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in support for single use in oauth2 or openid-connect, the next generation of Oauth will handle that I think.

But for now I guess your only option is to implement the logic in the API that receives the token. The access token is meant to have a certain lifetime.

the other option is to use reference tokens , then the API needs to ask the token provider on each request. But still you need to cancel it after each use.